# No se puede crear mas de un indice agrupado en la tabla

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Tengo una tabla (Areas) la cual tiene un solo 'clustered index' (campo Name), recientemente debí agregar un ViewModel en una vista y me encontré con un error fatal al ejecutar el proyecto. Dejo captura del mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro respuesta para este error, ya que evidentemente la tabla tiene un indice agrupado, pero en nigún momento estoy intentando agregarle otro.

Adjunto parte de código del ViewModel donde se relaciona a la entidad 'Candidate' con la entidad 'Area':

```
    ...
    public int CandidateAreaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Posición")]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Areas.Area> Area { get; set; }
    ...
```

Y aquí dejo el fragmento de codigo donde defino la entidad de relación 'CandidateArea'

```
public class CandidateArea
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Candidate")]
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_CandidateArea", 1, IsUnique = true, IsClustered = false)]
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }

    public virtual Candidates.Candidate Candidate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Area")]
    [Index("IX_CandidateArea", 2, IsUnique = true, IsClustered = false)]
    [Required]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    ...
```

Como se puede observar en este segundo fragmento, le estoy indicando a entity framework via DataAnnotation que el Id de Area no es un indice agrupado (o clustered index).

Esto me deja sin respuesta a porqué salta el error de que sí existe otro indice agrupado.

> ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Me pude dar cuenta de que esta excepción solo sale cuando cambio de schema las tablas de mi db, por ejemplo, la tabla 'Areas' ahora pertenece al esquema 'shared', y no al por defecto 'dbo'. Por eso me llama la atención el mensaje de la excepción, ya que menciona a la tabla con el schema viejo...

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que al cambiar el schema de las tablas, me faltaba especificarle el nuevo schema a cada tabla en el metodo OnModelCreating de mi DBContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("shared");
    ....
```

Agregando esa linea de Default Schema se solucionó el problema.